# Removing a Primary Key (Clustered Index) to increase Insert performance

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, clustered-index, database-performance

We've been experiencing SQL timeouts and have identified that bottleneck to be an audit table - all tables in our system contain insert, update and delete triggers which cause a new audit record.

This means that the audit table is the largest and busiest table in the system.  Yet data only goes in, and never comes out (under this system) so no `select` performance is required.

Running a `select top 10` returns recently insert records rather than the 'first' records.  `order by` works, of course, but I would expect that a select top should return rows based on their order on the disc - which I'd expect would return the lowest PK values.

It's been suggested that we drop the clustered index, and in fact the primary key (unique constraint) as well. As I mentioned earlier there's no need to `select` from this table within this system.

What sort of performance hit does a clustered index create on a table? What are the (non-select) ramifications of having an unindexed, unclustered, key-less table? Any other suggestions?

**edit**

our auditing involves CLR functions and I am now benchmarking with & without PK, indexes, FKs etc to determine the relative cost of the CLR functions & the contraints.

After investigation, the poor performance was not related to the `insert` statements but instead the CLR function which orchestrated the auditing. After removing the CLR and instead using a straight TSQL proc, performance improved 20-fold.

During the testing I've also determined that the clustered index and identity columns make little or no difference to the insert time, at least relative to any other processing that takes place.

```
// updating 10k rows in a table with trigger

// using CLR function
PK (identity, clustered)- ~78000ms
No PK, no index - ~81000ms

// using straight TSQL
PK (identity, clustered) - 2174ms
No PK, no index - 2102ms
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Kimberly Tripp - the Queen of Indexing - having a clustered index on a table actually helps INSERT performance:

> **The Clustered Index Debate Continued**
>
> - **Inserts are faster in a clustered table** (but only in the "right"
>     clustered table) than compared to a heap. The primary problem here is
>     that lookups in the IAM/PFS to determine the insert location in a heap
>     are slower than in a clustered table (where insert location is known,
>     defined by the clustered key). Inserts are faster when inserted into a
>     table where order is defined (CL) and where that order is
>     ever-increasing.

Source: blog post called [The Clustered Index Debate Continues....](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)

Comment: I found that this held true especially as the table size increased.

Answer (score 4):

A great test script and description of this scenarion is available on Tibor Karaszi's blog at [SQLblog.com](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/08/14/are-inserts-quicker-to-heap-or-clustered-tables.aspx)

My numbers don't entirely match his - I see *more* difference on a batch statement than I do with per-row statements.

With the row count around one million I fairly consistently get a single-row insert loop on clustered index to perform slightly faster than on a non-indexed (clustered taking approximately 97% as long as non-indexed).

Conversely the batch insert (10000 rows) is faster into a non-indexed rather than clustered index (anything from 75%-85% of the clustered insert time).

```
clustered - loop        - 1689
heap      - loop        - 1713
clustered - one statement - 85
heap      - one statement - 62
```

He describes what's happening on each insert:

> **Heap:** SQL Server need to find where the row should go. For this it
>   uses one or more IAM pages for the heap, and it cross references these
>   to one or more PFS pages for the database file(s). IMO, there should
>   be potential for a noticable overhead here. And even more, with many
>   users hammering the same table I can imagine blocking (waits) against
>   the PFS and possibly also IAM pages.
>
> **Clustered table:** Now, this is dead simple. SQL server navigates the
>   clustered index tree and find where the row should go. Since this is
>   an ever increasing index key, each row will go to the end of the table
>   (linked list).

Answer (score 2):

A table *without* a key? Not even an auto-incrementing surrogate key? :(

As long as the key is *monotonically increasing* the index maintenance upon insert should be good -- it's just "added at the end". The "clustered" just means the physical layout of the table follows the index (as the data is part of the index). As long as the index isn't fragmented (see *monotonically increasing* bit) then the cluster itself/data won't be logically fragmented and this shouldn't be a performance issue. (If there are updates then the clustering is a slightly different story: the record updated may "grow" and cause fragmentation.)

My suggestion is, if that is the chosen route then ... *benchmark it* with realistic data/load and then decide if such suggestions are warranted. It would be nice to see is this change was decided upon, and why.

Happy coding.

---

Also, any reliance upon order excepting that from an `ORDER BY` is flawed by design. It may work now, but it is an implementation detail and may change in subtle ways (as simple as a different query plan). With the auto-increment key, an `ORDER BY DESC` would always produce the correct result (bear in mind that auto-incremeent IDs can be skipped, but unless "reset" they will always be increasing based on insert order).

Comment: Cheers. I'm not relying on the order, I'm just using it in manager to demonstrate that the index is not ensuring the rows are placed on disk in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 2):

My primitive understanding is that even INSERT operations are usually faster with a clustered index, than with a heap.  Additionally, disk-space requirements are lower with clustered indexes.

Some interesting tests / scenarios that might shed some light for your particular circumstance: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917672.aspx.