# Better insert performance on a table only with a clustered index or a table without any index on SqlServer 2008?

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert, clustered-index

**Note, I am not talking about a clustered index against a non-cluster index, I mean a clustered index comparing to no index at all for inserting performance.**

I saw lots of links as below said that, a clustered index has better performance against no index even for insert operation, due to IAM/PFS/bitmap/..., but with my testing, seems no index is faster than cluster index, what's the problem?

[Removing a Primary Key (Clustered Index) to increase Insert performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264820/removing-a-primary-key-clustered-index-to-increase-insert-performance)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297861

my test scripts:

```
-------------------------------------------
--prepare table with clustered index
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BigTable_CI](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BigChar] [char](4100) NOT NULL
) 
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_BigTable_CI
    ON BigTable_CI(id)
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BigTable_CI] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_BigTable_BigChar_CI]  DEFAULT ('a') FOR [BigChar]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDataToBigTable_CI]
(@NumberOfRows bigint)    
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Counter int = 0;
    DECLARE @Start   datetime = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @End     datetime;
    DECLARE @ElapsedTime int = 0; 
    DECLARE @RowsPerSecond int = 0;

    WHILE (@Counter < @NumberOfRows)
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO dbo.BigTable_CI DEFAULT VALUES;
           SELECT @Counter += 1;
        END; 

    -- Calculate elapsed time and rows/second
    SET @End = GETDATE(); 
    SET @ElapsedTime = CONVERT(INTEGER, DATEDIFF (second, @Start, @End));
    SET @RowsPerSecond = @NumberOfRows/@ElapsedTime;

    -- Record results in local table
    INSERT INTO dbo.Results
    (StartTime, EndTime, ElapsedTime, NumberOfRows, RowsPerSecond) 
    VALUES (@Start, @End, @ElapsedTime, @NumberOfRows, @RowsPerSecond);

    RETURN;


-------------------------------------------
--prepare table without any index at all.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BigTable_NI](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BigChar] [char](4100) NOT NULL
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BigTable_NI] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_BigTable_BigChar_NI]  DEFAULT ('a') FOR [BigChar]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddDataToBigTable_NI]
(@NumberOfRows bigint)    
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Counter int = 0;
    DECLARE @Start   datetime = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @End     datetime;
    DECLARE @ElapsedTime int = 0; 
    DECLARE @RowsPerSecond int = 0;

    WHILE (@Counter < @NumberOfRows)
        BEGIN
           INSERT INTO dbo.BigTable_NI DEFAULT VALUES;
           SELECT @Counter += 1;
        END; 

    -- Calculate elapsed time and rows/second
    SET @End = GETDATE(); 
    SET @ElapsedTime = CONVERT(INTEGER, DATEDIFF (second, @Start, @End));
    SET @RowsPerSecond = @NumberOfRows/@ElapsedTime;

    -- Record results in local table
    INSERT INTO dbo.Results
    (StartTime, EndTime, ElapsedTime, NumberOfRows, RowsPerSecond) 
    VALUES (@Start, @End, @ElapsedTime, @NumberOfRows, @RowsPerSecond);

    RETURN;   

-------------------------------------------
--prepare the results table
    create table dbo.Results 
    (
        StartTime datetime, 
        EndTime datetime, 
        ElapsedTime int, 
        NumberOfRows int, 
        RowsPerSecond int
    )

-------------------------------------------
--run scripts:
    exec [dbo].[AddDataToBigTable_NI] 1000000
    exec [dbo].[AddDataToBigTable_CI] 1000000
```

Comment: see as:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/600d34c6-d143-4487-bcc8-2876e4a82523/better-insert-performance-on-a-table-only-with-a-clustered-index-or-a-table-without-any-index-on

Answer (score 0):

**For any insert operation, no index is faster than with an index**. When you have an index on a table, after insertion of each row, the database server has to allocate a reference to the row in the bitmap index or index repository, which is overhead to the server. This affects the number of rows inserted per second.